# Node at the origin?

Tags: dynamical-systems

We're given the following dynamical system
$$\dot{x} = -x - \frac{y}{\log(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})} $$
$$\dot{y} = -y + \frac{x}{\log(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2})} $$
And then asked to show that the origin is a stable node for the linearized system, and a stable spiral for the nonlinear system.

First, I converted the system to polar, giving me the following
$$\dot{r} = -r $$
$$\dot{\theta} = \frac{1}{\log(r)} $$
When I plotted the phase plane in wolfram, I do in fact see that the origin is a stable node/spiral, despite the dynamical system not being defined there. What I'm not sure how to proceed is dealing with the linearization. We have that $\frac{\partial \dot{\theta}}{\partial r} = \frac{-1}{r(\log(r))^2} $, which is neither defined at the origin nor is its limit. How do I consider the linearization about the origin then?

Comment: The factor $\frac1{\log r}$ goes to zero as $r\to 0$. So the linearization is the straight exponential fall towards the origin.